# Free ASP.NET shoutbox/chat

Tags: c#, asp.net, chat, chatroom

I am searching for a simple and **free ASP.NET C# shoutbox/chat application**, so i can integrate it in a small gamming portal.

The only important thing is that it should have some sort of "banned list", **where the admin can ban and unban people.**

So far i got no luck on finding something with this ban functionality, i hope you guys know something like this...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Simple text chat only ? ... 

Do you know any basic C# or VB?
You could write this yourself with very little coding.

Comment: I've used a few but I won't mention them as they are riddled with massive security holes. I'd steer clear of most cheap/free .NET based solutions if this is a concern.

Comment: @Wardy i know C# but because this was so simple I though there was something solid already done at the time. Eventually I ended up making one myself, with few bugs but did the job, you can check it here -> http://fantasy-world-cup-2010.click.pt/game1/mysquad.aspx.

Comment: @TheCodeKing thanks for the advice, in my case security wasn't a concern but I will keep it in mind for future works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it happened, Scott Hanselman posted about a little gem known as SignalR and how to use it to implement a very simple chat program just today. Pretty interesting stuff.

> But can I make a chat application in 12 lines of code?

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx

See it running here:
http://chatapp.apphb.com/

The banning/unbanning feature you mention would need some work of your own though.

Not sure if its the easiest way to get chat into your site, but its certainly the most interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [chatango.com](http://chatango.com)? It adds chat facilities on any web page. There might be similar alternatives to this as well.

Also, Steve Orr wrote an ASPx Control for chatting. Not sure how secure it is. 
check this link : http://steveorr.net/articles/WebChat.aspx